# mongoDB adding specific data to db Replica

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb

I'm currently looking if there is anyway for a person to replicate given info on a mongodb DB?
my idea is to only send a certain type of data, let's say, if a document has the field "height", that only documents with a height value higher than let's say 10, would be sent to the replica.

Is this possible? and if so, could you please explain or give a link to where this might be properly documented?

Thank you.

PS: this is for a java/jsp project, so I'm adding these tags in case there are built-in commands for this in the java driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is "yes" and "no".

[Replica Sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) will not provide this functionality. Replica Sets are just that a set of replicas or clones where each node contains the same data. So there's no easy "out of the box" way to do what you want.

However, replication works via a special ["oplog" collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Oplog). This is an actual collection in the DB that contains all of the recent changes to the data.

In theory you can "tail" this oplog and selectively apply changes. In fact people have done this. However, this is not a widely supported feature and it will definitely require several hours (or days) of effort to make work.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, is there any way to do what I want with some other functionality? master/slave connections? or even sharding?
if not, is it possible for you to tell me how to modify the oplog? and if so, if it's possible to do it from within a java program?

Comment: so, I searched on the database, it might be possible to do it if I do a direct edit of the oplog.rs' data, I'd have to do this edit specifically on the program it seems, however, I don't see any way to target a specific server to send this data to, do you know of any way?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that what I need isn't this at all, will be setting up different databases and populating them separatelly, whilst keeping the main database with a replica set.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: ok, so I've found out an even better way to do this, with replicas,
we can set up which collection the replicas access in local.slaves.*
all I need now is to set up a different collection, but, to simulate the oplog.rs I need to find a way to not have the _id field being generated...